# For which $n,p$ does $\cfrac {5n^2-3n}{2}=2^p-1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

For which $n,p$ does $\cfrac {5n^2-3n}{2}=2^p-1$, where $n,p$ are positive integers

Comment: Do you mean you have proven that the only solutions are $(1/1)$ and $(2/3)$ ?

Comment: @Peter, from the [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hqa0wcxrj2) - I hope I am not wrong!

Comment: We have infinite many choices for $n$ and $p$. A plot will not help.

Comment: $(10n-3)^2=5.2^{p+3}-31$.  That leads to two Pell-like equations, $x^2=5y^2-31$ and $x^2=10y^2-31$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an elementary solution. But you can solve it in integers.

$(10n-3)^2=5\cdot 2^{p+3}-31$. Clearly $p+3\ge 0$.

- If $p+3=3k, k\ge 0$, then $(5(10n-3))^2=\left(5\cdot 2^k\right)^3-775$. But $a^2=b^3-775$ has $14$ integral solutions (see http://oeis.org/A081120 and http://oeis.org/A081120/b081120.txt), which can be found with a program or [these tables](http://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/mordell.html#tbl5).

  $$(a,b)=(\pm 15,10), (\pm 78,19), (\pm 85, 20), (\pm 585,70),$$

  $$(\pm 715,80), (\pm 2167815, 16750), (\pm 4321215,26530)$$
     This gives the solutions $(n,p)=(0,0),(2,3),(-14,9)$.
- If $p+3=3k+1, k\ge 0$, then $(10(10n-3))^2=\left(5\cdot 2^{k+1}\right)^3-3100$. But $a^2=b^3-3100$ has $2$ integral solutions (http://oeis.org/A081120/b081120.txt), which are $(a,b)=(\pm 70, 20)$. This gives $(n,p)=(1,1)$.
- If $p+3=3k+2, k\ge 0$, then $2^{p+3}\equiv 4\pmod{7}$, so $5\cdot 2^{p+3}-31\equiv 3\pmod{7}$, which is not a quadratic residue.

This uses results from $1998$ in Mordell Equations (from [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000281602647)). In particular, $y^2=x^3+k$ is solved in integers for all $0<|k|\le 10^4$, and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=mordell&sort=&language=&go=Search) gives lists of the numbers of solutions for each $k$.